# Android emulator infinite loading and errors when GPU emulation is enabled

Tags: android-emulator, gpu, emulation

I have downloaded the entire Android SDK from the official website and I installed a new emulator (Android 4.0.3). As long as I don't have GPU emulation enabled it works (even if it need about 5 minutes to start and then uses a lot of resources) but when I enabled it the emulator enters a loop or something and it never loads. When I look at the Task Manager I see the memory usage growing up until a Windows message displays a warning about the low memory that's left (so, I have to close it).

When I execute *"adb logcat"* I get this repeating error:

```
E/EGL/Emulation < 113>: RcMakeCurrent returned EGL_FALSE
E/EGL/Emulation < 113>: tid 114: egMakeCurrent<976>: error 0x3006 <EGL_BAD_CONTEXT>
E/libEGL        < 113>: egMakeCurrent:674 error 3006 <EGL_BAD_CONTEXT>
E/SurfaceFlinger< 113>: Couldn't create a working GLES context. checks logs. exiting...
```

My computer's graphic card is a nVidia 8400 GS 512 Mb, my processor is a 3,2 Ghz Intel, it doesn't support hardware virtualization, I can run WebGL. Maybe this information may be of use for the detection of the problem.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Same here, but emulator crashes after a while: "Unhandled exception at 0x64a8000c in emulator-arm.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction." with stacktrace to libOpenglRender.dll!64a8000c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was fixed with SDK Tools revision 19

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28529

Comment: Thanks man. It looks like Google is serious about the developer's work.

Comment: @tomash I am facing same problem.I had already android SDK tools rev 19, it did not work.So updated to rev. 20. Still not working. Any idea how to solve this ? i am using ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: @AndroidKiller no idea, I'm using Windows

Comment: @tomash it was problem with ADT 20 and SDK rev 20.fixed by reverting back.